# TypeScript: How to write an interface for an array of objects that each represent a class for which each has the same function names

Tags: typescript

I'm importing Circle, inserting it into an array called `nodeObjects`, then looping over the array and for each object in the array I'm calling `update` and `draw`. I can ensure that all objects I insert into the array will all have `update` and `draw` functions.

I've had a stab at writing the interface but I get the error

```
Argument of type '(object: NodeObjectInterface) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'object' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'NodeObjectInterface': update, draw ts(2345)
```

The code with the error points marked...

```
import { Circle } from './circle';

interface NodeObjectInterface {
  update(): void;
  draw(): void;
}

class Nodes {

  canvasWidth: number;
  canvasHeight: number;
  circle: object;
  nodeObjects: object[];

  constructor(width: number, height: number) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvasHeight = height;
    this.circle = new Circle(this);
    this.nodeObjects = [this.circle];
  }
  update(tick: number) {
    this.nodeObjects.forEach((object: NodeObjectInterface) =>
//                                           ^ error
      object.update(tick)
    );
  }

  draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {

    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);

    this.nodeObjects.forEach((object: NodeObjectInterface) =>
//                                           ^ error
    object.draw(ctx)
  );
  }
}

export { Nodes };
```

and the circle that imported code is

```
interface NodesInterface {
    canvasWidth: number;
    canvasHeight: number;
  }

class Circle {
  canvasWidth: number;
  canvasHeight: number;
  constructor(nodes: NodesInterface) {
    this.canvasWidth = nodes.canvasWidth;
    this.canvasHeight = nodes.canvasHeight;
  }
  update(tick: number) {
     //
  }
  draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
  }
}

export { Circle };
```

UPDATE

```
export interface ClickedInterface {
  click(event: MouseEvent): void;
  mouseWheel(event: MouseEvent): void;
  mouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void;
  mouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void;
  mouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void;
}

interface NodeObjectInterface {
  update(tick: number): void;
  draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void;
}

class Nodes implements ClickedInterface {

  canvasWidth: number;
  canvasHeight: number;
  circle: object;
  nodeObjects: NodeObjectInterface[];

  constructor(width: number, height: number) {
    this.canvasWidth = width;
    this.canvasHeight = height;
    this.circle = new Circle(this);
    this.nodeObjects = [this.circle];
//                         ^ error
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-unused-expression
    new InputHandler(this);
  }
  update(tick: number) {
    this.nodeObjects.forEach((object) =>
      object.update(tick)
    );
  }

  draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {

    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);

    this.nodeObjects.forEach((object) =>
    object.draw(ctx)
  );
  }

  click(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('click');
  }
  mouseWheel(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('wheel');
  }
  mouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('down');
  }
  mouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('up');
  }
  mouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('move');
  }
}

export { Nodes };
```

Leaves the only error as

```
(property) Nodes.circle: object
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'NodeObjectInterface': update, draw ts(2739)
```

PARENT to Nodes

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Nodes } from './nodes';
import './scss/App.scss';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const canvasWidth = 820;
  const canvasHeight = 620;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;
        const nodes = new Nodes(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        let now = 0;
        const tickLoop = (epoch: number) => {
          const tick = epoch - now;
          now = epoch;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          nodes.update(tick);
          nodes.draw(ctx);
          requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
        };
        requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <canvas
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
    >
    </canvas>
  );
};

export { App };
```

Comment: Shouldn't `nodeObjects` have a `NodeObjectInterface` type?

Comment: maybe? how would i express that?

Comment: In your `Nodes` class, replace `nodeObjects: object[];` with `nodeObjects: NodeObjectInterface[];`

Comment: `this.nodeObjects = [this.circle];` now gives the error `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'NodeObjectInterface': update, draw ts(2739)`

Comment: I see, that means your `Circle` class also has to implement `NodeObjectInterface`. So `class Circle` should be replaced with `class Circle implements NodeObjectInterface`. it already has the `draw` and `update` methods, so I am assuming that is what you wanted.

Comment: I posted an update above, you have helped me progress but I'm still getting one error, I didnt update anything in Circle

Comment: You get that error because `this.circle` doesn't implement the interface (i.e. it's missing those two methods - update, draw). However, in the interface they don't take any parameters, yet in the `Circle` class, they do have a tick and a context.

Comment: when I add `class Circle implements NodeObjectInterface {` I get the error `Cannot find name 'NodeObjectInterface'.ts(2304)` If i then add it I still have the same issue with `this.nodeObjects = [this.circle];`

Comment: That is because the interface is not exported, so you can't use it in other files until you do. Just replace `export { Nodes };` with `export { Nodes, NodeObjectInterface };`

Comment: still the same errors, I think there maybe confusion between the update and draw function being on both nodes and circle? Circle does not need to call update or draw in nodes

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You add the circle in your nodeObjects list, and parse it to call draw and update on each object in that list. The thing is, Nodes::circle should also implement the interface, not have a type of object.

Comment: I added the parent to nodes above, that calls `draw` and `update` in nodes

Comment: A broken sandbox here  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-3uziy

Comment: I have moved the NodesObjectInterface to the circle.tsx file, export it and import it in nodes.tsx. The error was cleared. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-pm7r0

Comment: ok I got it now, there was no need to export the interface from Circle but on the nodes constructor I see you set `circle: NodeObjectInterface;` Thank you !